# Pointer is changing after function call, C

Tags: c, pointers

So I've written this program to represent a car park as a bitset, each space in the car park being one bit. I have a checkSpace function to check if a space is occupied or not and for some reason the pointer to my car park bitset changes or the data changes after I pass it into the function. To test it I set up the car park, I checked a space, then checked it again immediately after and for some reason the return value is changing when it shouldn't be. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    struct carPark{
        int spaces, levels;
        unsigned char * park;
    };

    struct carPark * emptyCarPark(int levels, int spaces){
        int chars = (spaces*levels)/8;
        if((spaces*levels)%8 != 0){
            chars++;
        }
        unsigned char park[chars];
        for (int i = 0; i < chars; ++i){
            park[i] = 0;
        }
        unsigned char * ptr  = &park[0];
        struct carPark * myPark = malloc(sizeof(struct carPark));
        myPark->park = ptr;
        myPark->spaces = spaces;
        myPark->levels = levels;
        return myPark;
    }

    int checkSpace(int level, int spaceNum, struct carPark * carpark){
        int charPosition = ((level*carpark->spaces) + spaceNum)/8;
        int bitPosition = ((level*carpark->spaces) + spaceNum)%8;
        if(carpark->park[charPosition]&&(1<<bitPosition) != 0){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
        struct carPark * myPark = emptyCarPark(5,20);
        printf("1st check: %d\n",checkSpace(1,1,myPark));
        printf("Second check: %d\n",checkSpace(1,1,myPark));
        return 0;
    }
```

So when I run the program I get:

```
    1st check: 0
    Second check: 1
```

Comment: What's the expected value? When I ran it, I get 1st check: 0
Second check: 0

Comment: That's what it should be, the other answer has cleared it up now, i'm guessing that was just junk values that appeared to be correct

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code below - in emptyCarPark() you are allocating the park array on the stack, and then returning a pointer to it.  As soon as the function returns, the park array is no longer allocated and you have a dangling pointer - for more information, see: [Cause of dangling pointers (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_dangling_pointers)

```
    unsigned char park[chars];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars; ++i){
        park[i] = 0;
    }
    // This is the pointer to an object on the stack.
    unsigned char * ptr  = &park[0];

    struct carPark * myPark = malloc(sizeof(struct carPark));
    myPark->park = ptr;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I get it now, so would the correct way to do it be to make park a pointer rather than an array? "unsigned char * park = malloc(chars);"

Comment: Yes, I think that is the way to go.  Also, I don't think you need the ptr variable - "&park[0]" is the same as "park".

If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.